# How do you draw the tree in generative grammar for phrasal prepositional verbs such as "put up with?

Tags: grammar, verbs, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

I have the structure for transitive phrasals and for prepositional verbs, but I am having some trouble when I have to draw the tree for a phrasal prepositional verb. I know for sure it must contain a V-core and a V-shell, but I don't know where the "DO" should be placed. Is the object part of the PP?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed, Abril. I hope you find your answer somewhere. I'll just add for other viewers that I'd see 'put up with' as a transitive multi-word verb (ie a single lexeme) with the obvious single-word synonym 'tolerate'. But I know it doesn't help with your type of analysis.

Comment: Some people may think of it as a phrasal verb _put up_ transitivized with _with_ -- [[put up]][with]] -- and others as a three-word verb [put up with].  Still others may parse it as [[put] [up with]], but that seems less likely. Still, such strings can be parsed lots of ways.